# Formula Field: How to Calculate max of several custom fields, and output field name/label of the winner?

Tags: formula, custom-field

I am trying to capture the max number value of 3 custom fields, then output the field name/label of the winner. What's the best way to do this?

Right now I got:

Max(Field A, Field B, Field C) and its correctly show me the highest number between the 3, BUT, I want to show the field name/label, instead of the max numerical value. Is this possible with some manipulation, if so, how?

Maybe:

```
If (Max(Field A, Field B, Field C)= Field A, “Field A”, 
If(Max(Field A, Field B, Field C)=Field B, “Field B”, 
If(Max(Field A, Field B, Field C)=Field C, “Field C”, No Value Set)
)
)
```

Comment: To include more information, do not use comments, but **[edit]** the existing question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes this is possible with a formula you just need to make sure Text is returned with your value - For example - If you wish to add your own label to each Max value out of Three custom fields - you can use the following formula :

```
IF(MAX(Field_A__c,Field_B__c,Field_C__c)= Field_A__c,"Value A Is the Max = "+ TEXT(Field_A__c),$Label.OtherValue)
```

- You can also add custom label as shown $Label.OtherValue